# Reset the html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a div with lot of elements inside the div. For some scenario i want to reset the value for the div's element to the initial status.

Is there any way to do this??

```
if($(window).width()<=960){
    $('#desktopCart').html(/i want to reset this element/);
    } 

    if($(window).width()>960){
    $('#mobileCart').html("/i want to reset this element/");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by reset??

Comment: Reset it to it's original state, or empty it?

Comment: @Parrotmaster i want to reset to the original status

Comment: @MilindAnantwar  i want to reset to the original status

Comment: @rightPath In that case, Pawel S's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) of jquery

```
$("#divId").empty();
```

It will remove all the child elements and text in that particular element.

If you want to restore the initial state of the div, you should save the initial innerHtml to a variable a `document.ready()`.
Like,

```
   var desktopCart;
   var mobileCart;
    $(document).ready(function(){
     desktopCart=$('#desktopCart').html();
     mobileCart=$('#mobileCart').html();

    });
```

Then restore the html whenever you want,

```
if($(window).width()<=960){
$('#desktopCart').html(desktopCart);
} 

if($(window).width()>960){
$('#mobileCart').html(mobileCart);
}
```

Comment: It Removes content of the div element, but i want to reset the element .

Comment: i want to reset to the original status

Answer (score 1):

First clone the element instead of saving the content. Then use replaceWith to restore it.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var divClone = $("#mobileCart").clone();
      if($(window).width()<=960){
    $('#desktopCart').html(/i want to reset this element/);
    } 

    if($(window).width()>960){
      $("#mobileCart").replaceWith(divClone);
    }
    });
```

For further reference, please see the below link.

[How can I "reset" <div> to its original state after it has been modified by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557641/how-can-i-reset-div-to-its-original-state-after-it-has-been-modified-by-java)

Comment: It Removes content of the div element, but i want to reset the element

Comment: but HE wants to reset the element

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var initialValue =$('#mobileCart').html();
});
if($(window).width()<=960){
$('#desktopCart').html(initialValue);
} 

if($(window).width()>960){
$('#mobileCart').html(initialValue);
}
```

Comment: but HE wants to reset the element

Comment: @PratikJoshi Please stop spamming all answers. We know what he wants to do, and this does it.

Answer (score 1):

> What if I have multiple elements ? And want to save the elements' state at regular intervals ? And regularly reset them ? There might not be just one of them .... maybe I will have `a` and `p` and `div` and too many of them. But I want to reduce typing ? What do I do ?

I am glad you asked.

```
// Write Once: Use Anywhere functions

$.fn.reset = function () {    
    var list = $(this); // list of elements

    for(var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++){ 
        list.eq(i).text(list.eq(i).data("initValue"));    
    }
};

$.fn.saveState = function () {
    var list = $(this); // list of elements

    for(var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++){
        list.eq(i).data("initValue", list.eq(i).text());    
    }
}

$("div").saveState(); // simple call to save state instantly !

// value change!
$("div:nth-child(2)").text("99999");

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 960) {
        $("div").reset(); // simple call to reset state instantly !
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Ke6qJ/1/) <sup>Resize window</sup>