# Reset jQuery DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the a method and the following code to get an array id `div`s

```
arr = $('.card.recipe-slider');
```

which returns me (for the first time)

```
[<div class=​"card recipe-slider active" data-id=​"1">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"card recipe-slider" data-id=​"2">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"card recipe-slider" data-id=​"3">​…​</div>​]
```

But when I call the same method again, ( for the second time), my Jquery DOM array gets duplicated as follows

```
[<div class=​"card recipe-slider active" data-id=​"1">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"card recipe-slider" data-id=​"2">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"card recipe-slider" data-id=​"3">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"card recipe-slider" data-id=​"1">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"card recipe-slider" data-id=​"2">​…​</div>​, 
<div class=​"card recipe-slider" data-id=​"3">​…​</div>​
]
```

So my question is how can I avoid this duplication?

I tried followings

1 ) make the array blank

```
arr = []
... code
```

2 ) Get the `unique`

```
$.unique($('.card.recipe-slider'))
```

3 ) Clearing the array first

```
  $('.card.recipe-slider').empty();
   arr = $('.card.recipe-slider')
```

4 ) and I have seen some solutions with `cloning` and `replacing` , which I'm not quite clear and don't know if [that's the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557641/how-can-i-reset-div-to-its-original-state-after-it-has-been-modified-by-java).

### Edit

Complete code , almost... :), this works as a wizard where each div will display when user clicks next

```
#html
<div class='card recipe-slider active' data-id='1'>
   .. html
   <a class="btn btn-warning button-full button-large icon-left next">Next..</a> 
</div>
<div class='card recipe-slider' data-id='2'>
  .. html
   <a class="btn btn-warning button-full button-large icon-left next">Next..</a> 
</div>
<div class='card recipe-slider' data-id='3'>
  .. html
   <a class="btn btn-warning button-full button-large icon-left next">Next..</a> 
</div>
```

JS code

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.next', function(e){
    arr = [];
    arr = $('.card.recipe-slider');
    current_card = $(this).closest('.card')[0];
    id = current_card.dataset.id;

    $(arr[id]).addClass('active');
    $(current_card).removeClass('active');

  })
```

Comment: Please post the method. My guess is that more elements are being added to the dom so the second time more get returned

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the duplicates ARE added to the DOM, not just to the jQuery result, because only one of the $('"1') is active.

Comment: @WayneEllery thanks for the quick reply, I updated the question with more code..

Comment: @DirkHorsten, thanks for the quick reply, I updated the question with more code