# Clear (or change) input mask from input textbox (Using Jasny)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasny-bootstrap

I wish to change the input mask on a textbox depending on the value selected on a select list. The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchList").change(function () {
        $("#searchCriteria").val("");

        var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

        switch (value) {
            case "2":
                $("#searchCriteria").inputmask({ mask: '999999', placeholder: '' });
               break;
            default:
                alert('default'); // this alert pops up.
                $("#searchCriteria") ///I want to clear the mask here.
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried

```
$("#searchCriteria").unmask();
```

but get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unmask is not a function" error.

The documentation says '?' says 'any characters following will become optional' so I tried 
    $("#searchCriteria").inputmask({ mask: '?', placeholder: '' });

with no success.

It does appear that once the mask has been set, it cannot be changed or cleared, but I'm sure there is a way.

I have also tried            $("#searchCriteria").unbind();

Which cleared the mask, but would then not set it to anything else.

EDIT:
I am not tied down to using Jasny, any other suggestions welcome :)

The requirement I'm trying to fulfil is 'Change an input mask on an input textbox according to the selection in a dropdown list'.

Comment: Use `$("#searchCriteria").empty()` to clear all the children elements

Comment: Didn't work, it still retains the mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer from this SO question:

[How can I "reset" <div> to its original state after it has been modified by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557641/how-can-i-reset-div-to-its-original-state-after-it-has-been-modified-by-java)

Essentially, store the cloned state in a variable, and use this variable to restore the element to it's original state before re-assigning the mask.

The code now looks like this, switch statement has gone but that's for a non-related reason:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var searchCriteriaClone = $("#searchCriteria").clone();

    $("#searchList").change(function () {
        $("#searchCriteria").val("");
        $("#searchCriteria").replaceWith(searchCriteriaClone.clone());

        var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

        if (value === "2") {
            $("#searchCriteria").inputmask({ mask: "999999", placeholder: "" });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$("#searchCriteria").trigger("unmask");
```