# How to get a button to revert back to its default state in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have invoked some code in my HTML that puts a button in a state of having a background of white when it's clicked.

How do I click on the button and revert back to its original position? This is what I have so far in my code:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#button").css("background", "white");
});
```

What code should I put here to have it back to original form when clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I "reset" <div> to its original state after it has been modified by JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557641/how-can-i-reset-div-to-its-original-state-after-it-has-been-modified-by-java)

Comment: That has completely nothing to do with anything i asked buddy

Comment: It's exactly what you're asking buddy; how to return an element back to its original state.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var button = $("#button");
    if (button.css("background") === "white") {
        button.css("background", "black");
    } else {
        button.css("background", "white");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally simpler toggling a class on the button and using  css rules to manage the style differences:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass( "white_bg");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#button.white_bg{
   background:white;
}
```

Comment: yes...if code is before elements there is...can't attach events to something that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Use a toggle function

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
});

.highlight {
background: yellow;
}
```

from:

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  original_background = $("#button").css("background");
  $("#button").click(function(){
     if ($("#button").css("background")==original_background) {
        $("#button").css("background", "white");
     } else {
        $("#button").css("background", original_background);
     }
  });

})
```