# Reload div element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to reload only a part of a webpage, e.g. a `div`element ***without*** using AJAX or JQuery? I tried `document.getElementById("mydiv").reload();` but it obviously doesn't work.

Please, do not write JQuery or AJAX, only pure JavaScript!

Comment: No, there is no way to reload only some elements without ajax.

Comment: reload it from the server?

Comment: But since it's possible to do it with JQuery, then there should be a way to get the same result with JavaScript, because the the former is a subset of JavaScript?

Comment: No, there isn't a built-in way to reset an element to its original state. You can perhaps stash a copy of its initial contents, attributes, etc. as the page loads, then replace what becomes current when needed. ([`<template>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) would likely be appropriate then.)

Comment: Forgot to put a note: so far it's a client-side website. But even from within webserver, I'll need to resort to AJAX anyway?

Comment: Ajax really has nothing to do with jQuery, it's really called `XMLHttpRequest` and is available without jQuery as well. Sounds like you really mean you don't want to use jQuery, not ajax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557641/how-can-i-reset-div-to-its-original-state-after-it-has-been-modified-by-java This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are client-side only and you want to use JavaScript to update a `div` then replacing the inner html of the `div` might just do the trick.

Something like :

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "whatever";
```

Or if you prefer to use jquery :

```
$('#content').html('whatever')
```

Comment: What if the content (i.e. `innerHTML`) remains the same? What changes is the `div` element's `top` value, whose original value is described in an external CSS style. Is there a method to retrieve that initial value or should I record it manually, before making any changes to `div`?

Comment: Well this is completely different.  You can use two style rules in the CSS file.  Updating the `div` without jQuery would be cumbersome.  With jQuery it would be : `$( "#content" ).removeClass( "oldClass" ).addClass( "newClass" );`